# Scala simpledateformat

Tags: java, scala, datetime, casting, simpledateformat

Is possible to get any type of string and use it with simpledateformat?

I'm trying to do this:

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
var date_temp = format.parse("2014-12-21 00:19:58Z")
println(date_temp)
```

The result is:  Sun Dec 21 00:00:00 BRST 2014

But what I want is: "2014-12-21 00:19:58".

I want this to make an insert in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var date_temp = format.parse("2014-12-21 00:19:58Z")
```

to

```
var date_temp = format.format(format.parse("2014-12-21 00:19:58Z"))
```

Comment: I got this error: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: solution:
var date_temp =  format.format(format.parse("2014-12-21 00:19:58Z"))

Answer (score 1):

Simply print the date using the same `SimpleDateFormat` instance:

```
println(format.format(date_temp))
```

Without formatting the date, the `println` will use the default `toString` representation of the `Date` object:

> Converts this `Date` object to a `String` of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```